# WPF Data binding from ChangedEvent arguments in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm using c# and wpf.

I have an problem with DataBinding. I have a referance to a bluetooth communication dll and when connection done there is DataChanged event returns like DataChangedEventArgs arg. I'm simple version of handling it with

```
private async void BtOnValueChanged(object sender, DataChangedEventArgs arg)
{
     await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
           {
                    textblock1.Text=arg.data1;
                    textblock.Text=arg.data2;
                    image1.Visibility=(arg.data3 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
                    if(data2>100)
                         textblock1.Foreground=Color.Red;
           });
}
```

DataChangedEventArgs has a class like

```
public class DataChangedEventArgs
{
  public string data1 {get;set;}
  public double data2 {get;set;}
  public bool data3 {get;set;}
}
```

but I want to do it with Xaml Binding. Only a few things that I need to do with event handler. I tried to get it from direct binding Datachangedevent nothing was show up. Also tried to get all args like

```
public static DataChangedEventArgs DataArg; 
....
....
private async void BtOnValueChanged(object sender, DataChangedEventArgs arg)
{
     await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
           {
               DataArg=arg;
           });
}
```

also tried to bind source in code but I couldn't handle it.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: You need to learn basics of MVVM, especially how to notify the change at model (notification from Bluetooth) to view model and ultimately to view.

Comment: But app is not MVVM type also I'm new in WPF searched alot but couldnt find any similar kind of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a property instead of a static variable and a custom data type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```cs
public class MyBluetoothViewData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _data1;
    private double _data2;
    private bool _data3;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string data1 { get => _data1; set { _data1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("data1"); } }
    public double data2 { get => _data2; set { _data2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("data2"); } }
    public bool   data3 { get => _data3; set { _data3 = value; OnPropertyChanged("data3"); } }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

```cs
public MyBluetoothViewData DataArg { get; set; } = new();
```

In your event handler:

```cs
this.DataArg.data1 = arg.data1;
this.DataArg.data2 = arg.data2;
this.DataArg.data3 = arg.data3;
```

Then you can bind to it in the XAML

Comment: Partially works but not as expected. When I pass value on initialization gets value but does not update

Comment: Make sure `DataChangedEventArgs` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set the properties on the object individually `this.DataArg.data1 = arg.data1` and so on

Comment: I have no control on DataChangedEventArgs its a package for bluetooth. I can use it parser.Datachanged += datachangedevent but cannot change package itself. If there is a way let me know please.

Comment: In that case, create your own data type that does what I described in my last comment.  Something like `MyBluetoothViewData DataArg {get;set;} = new()`  I'll update the answer